# can reset boot vector point to internal flash on MPC55xx?

Tags: microcontroller, reset, bootstrapping

A basic question on MPC55xx microcontroller:
I configured the reset boot vector (4 bytes after RCHW) to point to an address in the internal flash memory but it didnt reach this address (the software didnt begin).
is it even possible?
The RCHW is in external flash memory and when the reset boot vector points to an address in the external flash memory, it works.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answare is NO.
the TLB updated automaticly in the BAM in such way that only one flash bank can be used after boot.
A reconfiguration of the TLB after boot cat allow accessing othe flash memory.